# How do I implement responsive typography with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I'm building a responsive web app with Bootstrap 4. I want the font size of all text to be reduced on mobile devices compared to desktop, so I added the following to my base css file as per the Bootstrap documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/):

```
 html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
```

However the font size remains fixed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Sass feature.

To have access to the media-breakpoint mixins and the size variables, you need to:

1. add a `custom.scss` file
2. `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`
3. and setup a Sass compiler

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 11):

I think the easiest way is to use **@media Queries**. Suppose you want to change the font size *responsively* for a content with class "class-name" or even for entire html tag, just add your media queries to end of your css file or any place inside it.

**Sample code:**

```
/*
####################################################
M E D I A  Q U E R I E S
####################################################
*/

/*
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Bootstrap 4 breakpoints
*/

  /* Small devices (landscape phones, 544px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 544px) {  
    .class-name {font-size: 16px;}
  }

  /* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 768px) {  
    .class-name {font-size: 30px;}
  }

  /* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .class-name {font-size: 40px;}
  }

  /* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {  
    .class-name {font-size: 48px;}
  }
```

more information can be found [here](https://bootstrapcreative.com/can-adjust-text-size-bootstrap-responsive-design/)

Answer (score 11):

As of **Bootstrap 4.3.1**, there is now **RFS** (Responsive Font Sizing)! However, as [explained in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/typography/#responsive-font-sizes), you must enable it using the `$enable-responsive-font-sizes` SASS variable.

RFS Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/jr8RbeNf2M

---

*Before* Bootstrap 4.3.1, you'd can implement responsive text using SASS. However you need to specify the desired appropriate selector(s) for text that you want to resize...

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
}

@import "bootstrap";
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/5pZDWAvenE

This could also be done using CSS only (no SASS):

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/E1MVXqp21D

Comment: In Rails make sure this code (html down to the last media-point-break) appears after the last import (@import "bootstrap";), instead of above it. And write it in application.scss

Comment: The Demo doesn't seem to work: https://www.codeply.com/go/5pZDWAvenE , the font size always stays the same.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4.5, i set `$enable-responsive-font-sizes: true;` before I import the bootstrap SCSS, however the font size does not change when I change the window size. What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but a good starting point is to enable responsive font sizes in v.4.5

```
$enable-responsive-font-sizes: true;
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach with loop

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

$font-sizes: (
    html: ( xs: 1rem, sm: 1.2rem, md: 1.3rem),
  );

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    @each $name, $values in $font-sizes {
      @each $n, $value in $values {
        @if($infix == "-#{$n}" or ($infix == "" and $n == 'xs')) {
          #{$name} { font-size: $value; }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent alternative. Just don't forget that applying 1rem to <html> means $font-size-base * 1. So you'd probably want 1rem as your max value. ie $font-sizes: (
  html: (
    xs: 0.75rem,
    sm: 0.813rem,
    md: 0.875rem,
    lg: 0.938rem,
    xl: 1rem
  ),
);

Comment: @JFK yeah, you right. Sorry, by "html" I meant any appropriate typography tag.