# Responsive text with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, responsive

Using bootstrap 4 I want to have different font styles for different break points. I know I can use media queries to do this, but on Bootstraps website it gives an example like so:

```
html {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  html {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
}
```

This can be found here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/typography/

My question is, is that regular CSS or is that SASS? Tried researching it and I have found pages on stack overflow of people saying they enter this into a normal CSS file. However, when I do that, it never works. So Im assuming this isn't normal CSS? Or if it is, what am I doing wrong? Do I have to declare something first for it to understand? I tried using an online SASS compiler but get a mixin declaration is missing. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe that's a reference to SASS mixins. See also https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Comment: It's SASS, but you can see a CSS only [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55439398/171456)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap Css only work when you use custome class or ID name then implement CSS on it. Simply use different class or ID name from Css default classes present or given in bootstrap. you must need to SASS compiler.

Check this :https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/

https://bootstrapcreative.com/can-adjust-text-size-bootstrap-responsive-design/